# Page-loop is looping content from custom loops on the same site. How to avoid that?

Tags: loop, page-template, homepage, customization, frontpage

i've made a custom home-page (with a template) and i'm using three loops on this site: two category-loops and on the bottom of the site the main loop for the page (the page content). the problem is: the first loops are fine but the third (the main page loop) is looping the content from one of the other two loops, not from the actual site!?!

i think this happens because the main page-loop is the last one on that page. how can i avoid that?

here's my code:

the first loop:

```
<?php
$posts = get_posts('category_name=slider');
foreach($posts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);
?>
    <div class="startslide" style="background-image:url(<?php $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 670,320 ), false, '' ); echo $src[0]; ?>)">
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
        <div class="subline"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

the second one:

```
<?php
$posts = get_posts('category_name=meilensteine&numberposts=3');
foreach($posts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);
?>
            <div class="meilpost">
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
              <p><?php echo excerpt(14); ?></p>
         </div>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
```

and the thir one (the main page loop):

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`wp_reset_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query)** after each one of your custom queries:

```
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

You might want to also look at the **[`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata)** function, which would potentially be a better fit for you.

**Update**
Try this:

```
<?php
global $post;
$tmp_post = $post;

$my_posts = get_posts( 'category_name=slider' );
foreach ( $my_posts as $my_post ) :
setup_postdata( $my_post );
?>
    <div class="startslide" style="background-image:url(<?php $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $my_post->ID ), array( 670,320 ), false, '' ); echo $src[0]; ?>)">
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
        <div class="subline"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php $post = $tmp_post; ?>

<?php
$tmp_post = $post;

$my_posts = get_posts( 'category_name=meilensteine&numberposts=3' );
foreach ( $my_posts as $my_post ) :
setup_postdata( $my_post );
?>
    <div class="meilpost">
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <p><?php echo excerpt(14); ?></p>
     </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php $post = $tmp_post; ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: i tried it both but it's not working?!?! nothing happens, the third loop still grabs posts from one of the first loops on that page!

Comment: Your third loop starts with <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
and doesn't seem to have any query to filter posts. So it is listing ALL posts. You need add a query_posts or any other filter if you want to exclude posts.

Comment: @JochenSchmidt - please see my updated post.

Comment: ok, your code comes close to the solution but now EVERY post from EVERY loop has "<?php the_title(); ?>" from the third loop (the main page loop)!?!?!

Comment: Replace `the_title()` in your custom queries with `$title = get_the_title( $my_post->ID ); echo $title;`.

Comment: You'll probably have to replace `the_permalink()` and `the_title_attributes()` as well. :-/

Answer (score 0):

The function wp_reset_query() should help http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query